# Access struct in union

Tags: c++, winapi

```
typedef struct _JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION {
  DWORD ControlFlags;
  union {
    DWORD  CpuRate;
    DWORD  Weight;
    struct {
      WORD MinRate;
      WORD MaxRate;
    };
  };
} JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION, *PJOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384.aspx

In the structure above how do I access/change MaxRate? I get ControlFlags like so:

```
JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION cpu;
cpu.ControlFlags = JOB_OBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_HARD_CAP;
```

Comment: give the struct a name and the union.

Comment: Its not my struct to give a name though

Comment: I would expect `cpu.MaxRate`. Does the obvious not work?

Comment: no the obvious failed

Comment: Failed how? What happened when you tried?

Comment: JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION has no member MaxRate, complains Visual Studio.

Comment: Is this even valid C++? I thought that anonymous structs were forbidden...

Comment: Anonymous structs are an extension provided by Microsoft's compiler, @rakete. GCC supports them, too. A warning is provided at the highest warning levels. If you don't want the Windows headers to use them, `#define NONAMELESSUNION`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my copy of `winnt.h` header, the struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct _JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION {
    DWORD ControlFlags;
    union {
        DWORD CpuRate;
        DWORD Weight;
    };
} JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION, *PJOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION;
```

There is indeed no `MinRate` or `MaxRate`. My guess is, they might have been added in some later version of the SDK (I only have VC2013 handy at the moment).

Look into getting a fresher copy of the SDK. Meanwhile, `LOWORD(CpuRate)` and `HIWORD(CpuRate)` should do.